# Which should I choose, Document Model or Relation Model?

Tags: database

In my application, I choose Document Model but I still have some questions.

Here is my example document:

```json
{
  "catalogs": {
    "cat-id1": {
      "name": "catalog-1",
      "createdAt": 123,
      "products": {
        "pro-id1": {
          "name": "product-1",
          "createdAt": 321,
          "ingredients": {}
        },
        "pro-id2": {
          "name": "product-2",
          "createdAt": 654,
          "ingredients": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "cat-id2": {
      "name": "catalog-2",
      "createdAt": 456,
      "products": {
        "pro-id3": {
          "name": "product-3",
          "createdAt": 322,
          "ingredients": {}
        },
        "pro-id4": {
          "name": "product-4",
          "createdAt": 655,
          "ingredients": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But ingredients in product is referrer to another Document.

```json
{
  "ingredients": {
    "ing-id1": {},
    "ing-id2": {}
  }
}
```

Document Model has several benefits:

- Easy to edit schema, like `if (user.first_name) user.first_name = user.name.split(' ')[0]`
- No need to `join`, easily take all data in once.

Also I know that:

> On updates to a document, the entire document usually needs to be rewritten.
> For these reasons, it is generally recommended that you keep documents fairly small and avoid writes that increase the size of a document .

> Main idea is: Which data model leads to simpler application code?

My question will be:

1. What size of Document should I keep?
2. My application already have a Relation DB, should I combined Document Model to Relation DB to reducing complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a relational database in use, I don't see a real benefit to using a document based DB as well.

Your Database schema seems simple enough to be using a relational DB. Wheras, if catalog entries would be very different from each other, you might consider a document based model. But this does not seem to be the case.

Therefore, my advice is, you stick with a relational model.

I would design the model like this:

1. A table for each entity (`catalog`, `product`, `ingredient`) where each entry has a unique Id
2. A relation table for each `n:m` relationship (`catalogProduct`, `productIngredient`) that only contain the Id of the entities of the relationship.

An example:

- The ingredients `ing1`, `ing2` and `ing3` are stored in the table `ingredient`.
- The products `prod1` and `prod2` are stored in `product`.
- `ing1` and `ing2` are needed for `prod1`
- `ing2` and `ing3` for `prod2`
- In `productIngredient` in each entry, you store the ID of an ingredient and the ID of the product it is used in.

  - `prod1` : `ing1`
  - `prod1` : `ing2`
  - `prod2` : `ing2`
  - `prod2` : `ing3`